# Как сделать чтобы работали все ползунки а не один

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть несколько одинаковых блоков. И один js и css код для них.
Но работает почему то только первый блок с ползунком, остальные не работают.

Прошу помочь решить проблему

```js
function showValue(val,slidernum) {
    var thumb = document.getElementById("sliderthumb" + slidernum);
    var shell = document.getElementById("slidershell" + slidernum);
    var track = document.getElementById("slidertrack" + slidernum);
    var fill = document.getElementById("sliderfill" + slidernum);
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider" + slidernum);
    var pc = val/(slider.max - slider.min);
    var thumbsize = 30; 
    var bigval = 350; 
    var smallval = 30; 
    var tracksize = bigval - thumbsize;
    var fillsize = 12;
    var filloffset = 7;
    var bordersize = 2;
    var loc = pc * tracksize;
  
    document.getElementById("blur").setAttribute("stdDeviation", val/10);
    thumb.style.top =   "0px";
    thumb.style.left =  loc + "px";
    fill.style.top =  filloffset + bordersize + "px";
    fill.style.left =  "0px";
    fill.style.width =  loc + (thumbsize/2) + "px";
    fill.style.height =   fillsize + "px";
    shell.style.height =   smallval + "px";
    shell.style.width =  bigval + "px";
    track.style.height =   fillsize + "px";
    track.style.width =  bigval - 4 + "px";
    track.style.left =  "0px";
    track.style.top = filloffset + bordersize + "px";
}
function setValue(val,num) {
    document.getElementById("slider"+num).value = val;
    showValue(val,num);
}

setValue(1,1);
```

```css
.slider, .slidervertical {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:100;
}
  .label {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:.02em;
  }
  .label.fun{
    color: #EB7F00;
  }
  .label.not-fun{
    color: #202D5D;
  }

  .slidershell {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    overflow:visible;
    filter: url(#goo);
  }
  
  .slidertrack {
    border-radius:4px;
    position:absolute;
    background: #202D5D;
  }
  

  .sliderfill {
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      position:absolute;
      pointer-events:none;
      border-radius:4px;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #A02166 0%, #F42796 100%);
      border-radius: 100px;
        box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(244, 39, 76, 0.5);
      }
  .sliderthumb {
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      display:block;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #A02166 0%, #F42796 100%);
      border-radius:50%;
      background-position:0px 0px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      border:0 none;
      padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:center;
      pointer-events:none;
  }
  

  
  input[type=range] {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    appearance:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0 none;
    background:transparent;
    color:transparent;
    overflow:visible;
  }
  

  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {width:40px;height:40px;
      border-radius:0px;border:0 none;background:transparent;-webkit-appearance:none;}
  svg {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

  .sadface {
    background: #fefefe;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: desaturate(lighten(#225378, 35%), 35%);
  }
  

  @media (max-width: 610px) {
    .label {
      display:none;
    }
    .slidershell {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
    <div class="miningBlockProgress">
      <div class="slidershell" id="slidershell1">
        <div class="slidertrack" id="slidertrack1"></div>
        <div class="sliderfill" id="sliderfill1"></div>

        <div class="sliderthumb" id="sliderthumb1"></div>

        <input class="slider" id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"
           oninput="showValue(value,1);" onchange="showValue(value,1);"/>
        </div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
        <filter id="goo">
        <feGaussianBlur id="blur" in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 26 -9.5" result="goo" />
        </filter>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: какие остальные?

Comment: У меня много таких блоков с ползунками, и они не работают, а только первый вот работает

Comment: правильно. потому что иденфикатор работает с первым только...на то он и **идентификатор** чтобы уникально идентифицировать что-то.......для нескольких - надо работать с классами

Comment: я когда меняю getElementById на getElementsByClassName - ничего не меняется, наоборот даже первый перестаёт работать. Подскажите как решить

Comment: ну правильно...потому что getElementsByClassName   возвращает **коллекцию** (там в самом названии заложено element**S** ).......по которой надо циклом проходить......а `getElementById ` возвращает **один** элемент

Comment: Заменил на querySelector - также

Comment: А вы всегда наобум разрабатываете? Что, по-вашему делает querySelector и что вы с ним делаете и что должно было сработать?

Comment: Я что не спрошу у вас, вы не можете мне сказать, или обьяснить как выделить эти элементы все?

Comment: Я вполне себе написал... Просто вы почему-то не читаете все комментарии........что было не ясно вот в этом комментарии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457929/#comment2606105_1457929 ?

Comment: Я уже перепробовал всё - 0

Comment: ...Всё - это что?

Comment: getElementById
getElementsByTagName
getElementsByClassName
querySelectorAll

Comment: Точно так же просто тыкая наобум?   .........ещё раз: со множеством - надо использовать 1. выборку по множеству (например по общему классу) ... 2. цикл по этому самому множеству....

Comment: Может вам это кажется легким, но я не понимаю вас. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что именно не ясно? Что можно не понять в словах **присвоить всем класс**? Или что не понятно в словах **использовать цикл** ?

Comment: Я прошу показать мне как это сделать в моём примере, потому что я не разбираюсь, а не подсказать

Comment: Ну этот ресурс для того, чтобы множество других разработчиков столкнувшихся с аналогичной проблемой - смогли найти решение. Тут не ресурс "в моём конкретном коде проблема - исправьте мне". Если вам нужен специалист, чтобы переписал код - вам на фриланс и подобные ресурсы

Comment: А как они в данном случае найдут решение? Если его даже тут нет, кучу бестолковых рассуждений. 
А решения так и нет

Comment: Если человек дуб-дубом, конечно, ничего, кроме рассуждений в  комментариях, которые **напрямую говорят что делать** не увидит ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

День добрый.
Выбранный Вами метод просмотрит DOM, но работает/возвращает ТОЛЬКО первый элемент.

Плюс, `id` является уникальным в шаблоне всей страницы и дублироваться не может.

Воспользуйтесь более [универсальным метод](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#querySelectorAll)м поиска `querySelectorAll`
Он возвращает все найденные элементы.

> Самый универсальный метод поиска – это elem.querySelectorAll(css), он возвращает все элементы внутри elem, удовлетворяющие данному CSS-селектору

Еще `id` измените на `class` или выборку проведите по селекторам. Далее пропустите через цикл `for select in elem.querySelectorAll(css)`.  css ето выбранный Вами селектор.